# Выбор тестов для запуска в Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, ant

Есть следующая проблема:
Необходимо настроить возможность в билде запускать тесты по одному/выбрав несколько конкретных.

На старом jenkins это было настроено с помощью плагина Extended Choice Parameter plugin и groovy скриптом

```
def testsNamesFile = new 
File("${System.getenv().get("JENKINS_HOME")}/workspace").listFiles().find {
    dir -> dir.name == binding.currentProject.name
}.listFiles().find {
    file -> file.name == "tests_names.txt"
}

if (testsNamesFile == null || !testsNamesFile.exists()) {
    return []
}

def checkboxesValues = []
def checkboxesDescriptions = []

/*
when you save a semicolon in an array, the script displays it out as 
different values
therefore replaceAll(",", "`")
 */
testsNamesFile.readLines().sort().each { l ->
def line = l.trim().replaceAll(",", "`")
def sepIdx = line.indexOf("__")
if (sepIdx != -1) {
    checkboxesDescriptions.add(line.substring(0, sepIdx))
    checkboxesValues.add(line.substring(sepIdx + 2))
}
}

def checkboxEnv = binding.getProperty("checkbox")

if (checkboxEnv != null && checkboxEnv == "value") {
return checkboxesValues
} else if (checkboxEnv != null && checkboxEnv == "description") {
return checkboxesDescriptions
} else {
return []
}
```

И при параметризованной сборке, можно было выбрать четбоксами нужные тесты.
Это реализовали разработчики на аутсорсе, сейчас появилась необходимость переехать на новый jenkins, но на нем скрипт не отрабатывает и четбоксы не появляются в сборке.

Есть способ заставить это работать, или каким либо ещё способом реализовать возможность выбора конкретных тестов?

Используем jenkins + Junit + Ant